# onSelectionChange gets interrupted when changing sheets in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function in a script that is connected to a sheet:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
    // code
}
```

The problem is that when I change to a different sheet the execution stops and a new execution starts on the new sheet.

**Is there any way to ensure that the previous execution will do all its tasks before terminating?**

EDIT:

I've come to realize that the issue is that a trigger won't always execute on an event if there is another invocation quick enough. And it seems that for this there is no fix.

Comment: You can use changeType perhaps to solve your problem also I believe these fuuction have to end in less than 30 seconds

Comment: I don't think the execution stops because there is another execution. All the executions are made. I think the issue is what @Cooper said. The code terminates because it does not manage to finish within 30 seconds. To verify if that is the case, go to the execution page and check if the execution completed successfully or returned an error message (failed).

Comment: Because the limitations are very strict, you should take full advantage ot the event object `e` in your code. This is why @Cooper says that you should use `changeType` because then you don't execute `//code` for every selection change.

Comment: How would I use `changeType` in this instance? Isn't `changeType` for an `onChange` trigger, which won't trigger on a selection change? I need my code to trigger every time the user changes selection. @Mario @Cooper

Comment: What are you getting on your 'Executions' page? @Ruan

Comment: All my execution say "Completed". I now realise that `onSelectionChange` never gets triggered if you change your selected and switch to a different page fast enough.

Comment: The trigger does get triggered and it also executes the code before a new action is triggered, so I am not completely sure what is the issue here. What is it that you want to achieve by using the trigger? @Ruan

Comment: @ale13 I think the problem is that when you change your selection and then change your selection again fast enough, then the first selection change never triggers `onSelectionChange`. Ideally, I want every selection change to trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not way of ensuring that all the selections are triggering the wanted function, especially if these changes are made rapidly.

However, depending on how does the code of your `onSelectionTrigger` trigger look like, you *may* be able to optimize it in such a way that all of your changes end up triggering it.